# mapping from xml to cobol field

Tags: mapping, cobol, wtx

I need to pass LOW-VALUES(am not very sure what kind would that be), as default for a copybook field, to the backend team. I use a wtx transform which converts xml to cobol

```
15 :abc       PIC X(15).
```

From the mainframe team I got this as sample for the field.

```
X'000000000000000000000000000000'
```

However when I use this rule, it fails because the number of characters is above 15. How can I pass the LOW-VALUES?

my rule map for the above cobol field

```
="X'000000000000000000000000000000'"
```

error meesage

```
Map:    Output: abc Field:123 Group:outputcbl
    Size of input item is greater than size of output item.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LOW-VALUE` in COBOL is a figurative constant. The value of this constant
is the character having the lowest ordinal position in the collating sequence used.

Assuming the character set in use is EBCDIC (as indicated in one of your comments to another answer) 
and the collating sequence has not
been overridden (probably a good assumption), a LOW-VALUE corresponds to binary zeros.

A `PIC X(15)` data item in COBOL occupies 15 bytes. Use a transformation that translates this
field into 15 bytes of binary zeros. The COBOL application will see this a `LOW-VALUE`.

Note: The value your 'Mainframe team' gave you is a hexadecimal string representation for 15 bytes of binary zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Low-values is simply all Hex zeros, so if you resize your rule map to contain 15 hex digits, all zero, you should be fine.

Comment: I want to send all low values in case the input is empty and send the input as it is in case if it is having some value. My wtx mapping has input xml utf8 to output cobol in ebcdic format

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the mapping technique you're using, so I can't help you with that, but if you want to use low values you need to get the hex string to the right number of characters